# How to improve SQL Server database query's performance?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server database select query which brings 60 columns from 10 tables via join. I need to fetch 3 Lac rows from database. It takes 20 seconds to fetch 3 Lac rows. I want to decrease this execution time to 10-12 secs.

I used the Database Tuning Advisor of SQL Server 2008 R2, it suggested me 2 create some indexes and statistics. I have created all this, but could not improved the performance of my query.

Can anybody suggest me right solution ???

Comment: Could you please tell me what is Lac?

Comment: Are the index statistics current?

Comment: Could you post the query and some more platform related information? Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Get us a query plan and the query. If you do not know how to get the query plan look at this : http://www.plixa.nl/how-to-read-query-execution-plans/